# what is purpose of order in mysql index

Tags: mysql

I have table person in that there is field contact number i want to add indexing on contact number.
In mysql what is the purpose on ordering while indexing some field.

INDEX `contact_number` (`contact_number` ASC))

Comment: while fetching records from that table and if your query has order by column e.g Name then if have created index on **Name** field then it will give you response very fast than without index on NAme with same query

Basically its better to give index on field which is used in order by while fetching data often..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now (mysql 5.7) the ASC/DESC is ignored by MySQL.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html

> An index_col_name specification can end with ASC or DESC. These keywords are permitted for future extensions for specifying ascending or descending index value storage. Currently, they are parsed but ignored; index values are always stored in ascending order.

If it is implemented some day it might be useful for composite indices:
http://explainextended.com/2009/04/27/descending-indexes/

Answer (score 2):

So far ASC and DESC in an index are simply ignored:

> An index_col_name specification can end with ASC or DESC. These
>   keywords are permitted for future extensions for specifying ascending
>   or descending index value storage. Currently, they are parsed but
>   ignored; index values are always stored in ascending order.

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html

I guess the idea is that if you use a column very often in ORDER BY and always use the same direction, you can write the index accordingly, so as to speed up the typical queries:

```
create index idx_logdate on logtable (logdate desc);
```

Typical query:

```
select *
from logtable
where logdate > date_sub(now(), interval 1 month)
order by logdate desc;
```

As mentioned, DESC in the index has no effect now, but may have effect in a future release.

Comment: As indexes are ASC only, does this mean that if you order by ASC on that indexed column will be quicker than order by desc?

Comment: @Thomas Clowes: Yes, this may be so. But only so little that you can put this aside as completely insignificant. How much slower would it be for you to find Millie Meyer in a telephone book if it had the last names in reverse alphabetical order Z-A instead of A-Z?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Interesting analogy, but I am more concerned about the use case where one wants to the first entries more regularly in a massive dataset. So an indexed INT where I want to access higher values more often would surely be best indexed as negative integers to take advantage of the ASC index..

Comment: I must admit I know too little about this. Aren't indexes usually trees where you have a kind of implicit binary search? Then it shouldn't matter whether to go the left branch or the right one. But well, I don't know really. And I don't bother to be honest :-)